# Can't get JQuery .stop to work properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using Jquery animate to have an image pop up upon hover over 'button' in a couple motions and then return. I am trying to use the stop function to prevent the image from jumping up and down when the cursor moves back and forth over the button.  I can't seem to get the stop function to work properly  . When I put the stop before the animate (I have put it before the first .animate, all of them and before the last one to no avail) the image wont pop up at all or else comes up incorrectly.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#bearup").hover(function(){
 $("#shopbears").animate({top:['-=120px','swing']},2000).animate({top:'+=0px'},2000)
 .animate({top:'+=50px'},3200).animate({top:'+=70px'});
 });
 });
```

I have created a fiddle for the .animate problem. http://jsfiddle.net/gerstley/dgWDy.  Perhaps someone can figure out a way to keep the motions from stacking up.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant markup and where exactly you were trying to call jQuery .stop ?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle? If not, I would recommend making one to help people more quickly solve your issue.

Comment: Where's the stops at ?

Comment: Sidenote, using stops with incrementing values will cause issues, and `+=0px` <- really ?

Comment: You're executing all of the `animate` functions immediately.  You can defer them by nesting them in the previous animation's callback function.  Then you should only need the `stop()` before the first `animate()`

Comment: @ponysmith That is incorrect, the animations will run in sequence, and since you have multiple animations in the queue, you really should call finish instead so that it finishes all the animations instead of just the currently animating one.

Comment: This is the markup with the .stops.  When I run this the image doesn't move.$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bearup").hover(function(){
    $("#shopbears").stop().animate({top:         ['-=120px','swing']},2000).stop().animate({top:'+=0px'},2000).stop()
.animate({top:'+=50px'},3200).stop().animate({top:'+=70px'});
  });
});

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't having an issue where the cursor is causing a hover, then unhover, then hover again as you move shopbears around, this might solve your issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#bearup").hover(function(){
 $("#shopbears")
  .finish()
  .animate({top:['-=120px','swing']},2000)
  .delay(2000)
  .animate({top:'+=50px'},3200)
  .animate({top:'+=70px'});
 });
});
```

Comment: +1 - finish() is the way to go here, and you don't see finish() used very often.

Comment: I ran the script from @robert McKee and it seemed to solve the stacking issue but whenever the cursor runs over the "bearup" area, the script restarts whether or not it was finished running.  Also the image isn't always getting back to the starting point after running.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of testing different options I found a solution that seems to consistently work. Using finish() instead of stop() is the answer but it appears that finish() has problems with .delay() (or at least delay() and animate() together).  So using animate() to create delays works best. I can't imagine many people would ever need this but you never know.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").mouseenter(function(){
$("#image") 
.finish().animate({top:['-=120px','swing']},2000)
.animate({top: '+=0px'},2000)
.animate({top:'+=50px'},3200)
.animate({top:'+=70px'})
;
});
});
```